# Selenium 2 - Android Server crashes when trying to SendKeys into a field

Tags: android, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using WebDriver Selenium-dotnet-2.11.0 and Android server 2.11.0. Tests are run by NUnit.

This works well for navigation around web pages and clicking elements. However, when I try to enter a value in a field (SendKeys), the .apk app on the device (a.k.a. Selenium-server) crashes due to an unknown error.

I'm using a real device HTC Desire Z1 (the one with slide-out keyboard).

The piece of code that leads to the crash is:

```
IWebElement _element;

_element = _driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginEmail"));
string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] + "Username"];
_element.SendKeys(username);
```

*username* is acquired correctly and doesn't contain any special characters, except '@', but I checked that it's not causing the problem.

Device debug log shows following error:

```
11-04 12:10:24.619: I/dalvikvm(3941): Could not find method android.view.KeyEvent.normalizeMetaState, referenced from method org.openqa.selenium.android.EventSender$2.run
11-04 12:10:24.619: W/dalvikvm(3941): VFY: unable to resolve static method 51: Landroid/view/KeyEvent;.normalizeMetaState (I)I
11-04 12:10:24.629: W/dalvikvm(3941): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
11-04 12:10:24.649: E/AndroidRuntime(3941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

I wonder what is the cause of the problem. I can't type anything into a field, but haven't found anyone else having this problem. It looks like either I'm doing something wrong or the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just upgrade to android server apk 2.1.3 and the send_keys works fine.